# Multi-line Strings

Tags: python, string, performance

Suppose, I want to define a two-line (or a multi-line) string.

I can do this in two ways:

- Using escape sequence for the newline character.`\n`
  Ex: `"This is the first sentence. \n This is the second sentence."`
- Using triple-quoted strings.
  Ex: `""" This is the first sentence.
         This is the second sentence."""`

Which is the more efficient or conventional ? Why ?

Comment: Triple quotes are more clear, since your text will be WYSIWYG.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am trying to ask will my choice affect my code's performance ? If it does, which option should I use !

Comment: Do whatever you prefer, this is completely opinion based. There will be no real difference in performance. Obviously for multiple lines or very long lines triple quotes will be more readable

Comment: @PM2Ring, yes, I saw that after thanks.

Comment: Triple-quoting is easy to read. OTOH, it doesn't play well with indentation. Performance differences between the two techniques are non-existent or infinitesimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm tempted to say it doesn't matter since each one still scans inside for escaped characters while parsing the text.

```
>>> print "a\n\tb"
a
        b
>>> print """a\n\tb"""
a
        b
```

Comment: Why didn't you just flag the question?

Comment: Didn't occur to me, I haven't flagged anything yet. And it didn't seem unreasonable to ask about